# Yarn quasar dev warning

Tags: vue.js, quasar

```
 App •  WARNING  •  UI  in ./node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.sass

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Deprecation Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($angle, 180) or calc($angle / 180)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

node_modules\quasar\dist\quasar.sass 41:9     sin()
node_modules\quasar\dist\quasar.sass 4401:16  root stylesheet


 App •  WARNING  •  UI  in ./node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.sass

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Deprecation Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($angle, 180) or calc($angle / 180)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

node_modules\quasar\dist\quasar.sass 49:9     cos()
node_modules\quasar\dist\quasar.sass 4402:17  root stylesheet


 App •  WARNING  •  UI  in ./node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.sass

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Deprecation Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(pow(-1, $i) * pow($rad, (2 * $i + 1)), fact(2 * $i + 1)) or calc(pow(-1, $i) * pow($rad, (2 * $i + 1)) / fact(2 * $i + 1))

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

node_modules\quasar\dist\quasar.sass 44:18    sin()
node_modules\quasar\dist\quasar.sass 4401:16  root stylesheet


 App •  WARNING  •  UI  in ./node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.sass

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Deprecation Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(pow(-1, $i) * pow($rad, 2 * $i), fact(2 * $i)) or calc(pow(-1, $i) * pow($rad, 2 * $i) / fact(2 * $i))

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

node_modules\quasar\dist\quasar.sass 52:18    cos()
node_modules\quasar\dist\quasar.sass 4402:17  root stylesheet


 App •  WARNING  •  UI  in ./node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.sass

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Deprecation Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(round($number * $power), $power) or calc(round($number * $power) / $power)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

node_modules\quasar\dist\quasar.sass 37:11    toFixed()
node_modules\quasar\dist\quasar.sass 4404:12  root stylesheet


 App •  WARNING  •  UI  in ./node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.sass

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
3 repetitive deprecation warnings omitted.

null


 App •  WARNING  • Compilation succeeded but there are warning(s). Please check the log above.
```

This is the warning I get. I don't really know what else you might need to help me. I would love to provide any necessery information you need to help me to solve this issue.

I've tried to delete node_modules folder and yarn.lock file and install everything again. I thought i have some issues with quasar. However, it did not help, wtill getting that warning.

Comment: https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/16535